# Возведение числа в квадрат incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int

Tags: java

```java
int a=2;
a=Math.pow(a,a);
```

Вот такой код. Он не работает. Не вижу ошибок. Но компилятор ругается:

> Error:(199, 45) error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int

Как вы поняли, на выходе должно получиться, что `а=4`.

Comment: @drakonoved для чего редактировать вопрос, который решён 4 года назад? Заняться больше нечем?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java запрещает и непущает из-за того, что метод pow класса Math возвращает вам `double` а вы хотите `int`. Ещё вам компилятор говорит, что так вы потерять можете в точности.

Так что вам надо или скастовать результат к `int` так

```
int a=2;
a=(int)Math.pow(a,a);
```

Или таки объявить переменную как `double` так

```
double a=2;
a=Math.pow(a,a);
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но почему компилятор не додумался, что если сделать pow двух целочисленных чисел, то результат тоже будет целочисленен?

Comment: @EgorRandomize, потому что компилятор считает себя глупее человека. Т.е. он полагает, что вы знаете о типе возвращаемого значения метода и знаете что получите на выходе double. Но при этом объявляете переменную как int. Компилятор запутался из-за того что программист по умолчанию не ошибается и, засим, попросил объяснить ему лучше что вы от него хотите.

Comment: технически - потому что в Java нет полиморфизма по возвращаемому типу. Т.е. не могут быть одновременно объявлены методы `int pow(int, int)` и `double pow(int, int)`

Answer (score 9):

Мне кажется вам вполне понятно написало. `Math.pow()` возвращает дробное число (`double`), очевидно что напрямую его присвоить нельзя. Напишите например так:

```
a=(int)Math.pow(a,a);
```

И кстати это не в квадрат а в степень `a`. Будьте аккуратны с переполнением `int`.